Stream sent via FFMPEG (NodeJS) to RTMP (YouTube) not being received
I am writing a very basic chrome extension that captures and sends video stream to a nodeJS server, which in turns sends it to Youtube live server.
Here is my implementation of the backend which receives data via WebRTC and send to YT using FFMPEG:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription } = require('@roamhq/wrtc');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/webrtc', async (req, res) => {
  const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

  // Start ffmpeg process for streaming
  const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-f', 'flv',
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-maxrate', '3000k',
    '-bufsize', '6000k',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-g', '50',
    '-f', 'flv',
    'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MY_KEY'
  ]);

  ffmpeg.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('FFmpeg error:', err);
  });

  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error('FFmpeg stderr:', data.toString());
  });

  ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('FFmpeg stdout:', data.toString());
  });

  // Handle incoming tracks
  peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
    console.log('Track received:', event.track.kind);
    const track = event.track;

    // Stream the incoming track to FFmpeg
    track.onunmute = () => {
      console.log('Track unmuted:', track.kind);
      const reader = track.createReadStream();
      reader.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('Forwarding chunk to FFmpeg:', chunk.length);
        ffmpeg.stdin.write(chunk);
      });
      reader.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Stream ended');
        ffmpeg.stdin.end();
      });
    };

    track.onmute = () => {
      console.log('Track muted:', track.kind);
    };
  };

  // Set the remote description (offer) received from the client
  await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(req.body.sdp));

  // Create an answer and send it back to the client
  const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

  res.json({ sdp: peerConnection.localDescription });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('WebRTC to RTMP server running on port 3000');
});


This is the output I get, but nothing gets sent to YouTube:

FFmpeg stderr: ffmpeg version 7.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)

FFmpeg stderr:   configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon

FFmpeg stderr:   libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100

FFmpeg stderr:   libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100


I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Optionally Here's the frontend code from the extension, which (to me) appears to be recording and sending the capture:
popup.js & popup.html


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('openCapturePage').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL('capture.html')
    });
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>StreamSavvy Popup</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>StreamSavvy</h2>
  <button id="openCapturePage">Open Capture Page</button>
</body>

</html>



capture.js & capture.html


let peerConnection;

async function startStreaming() {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      video: {
        cursor: "always"
      },
      audio: false
    });

    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [{
        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
      }]
    });

    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/webrtc', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sdp: peerConnection.localDescription
      })
    });

    const {
      sdp
    } = await response.json();
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));

    console.log("Streaming to server via WebRTC...");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error starting streaming:", error.name, error.message);
  }
}

async function stopStreaming() {
  if (peerConnection) {
    // Stop all media tracks
    peerConnection.getSenders().forEach(sender => {
      if (sender.track) {
        sender.track.stop();
      }
    });

    // Close the peer connection
    peerConnection.close();
    peerConnection = null;
    console.log("Streaming stopped");
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('startCapture').addEventListener('click', startStreaming);
  document.getElementById('stopCapture').addEventListener('click', stopStreaming);
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>StreamSavvy Capture</title>
  <script src="capture.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>StreamSavvy Capture</h2>
  <button id="startCapture">Start Capture</button>
  <button id="stopCapture">Stop Capture</button>
</body>

</html>



background.js (service worker)


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log("StreamSavvy Extension Installed");
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === 'startStreaming') {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL('capture.html')
    });
    sendResponse({
      status: 'streaming'
    });
  } else if (message.type === 'stopStreaming') {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL('capture.html')
    }, (tabs) => {
      if (tabs.length > 0) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
          type: 'stopStreaming'
        });
        sendResponse({
          status: 'stopped'
        });
      }
    });
  }
  return true; // Keep the message channel open for sendResponse
});




reader.on('data', (chunk) => ffmpeg.stdin.write(chunk)) Out of curiosity, have you tried reader.pipe(fmpeg.stdin) directly? Also, https://www.jameskerr.blog/posts/pipe-nodejs-readable-stream-into-child-process/ this article mentions that you need to wrap the child process in a transform stream.

I had a similar issue recently and added the flag '-b:v', '3000k' which sets the bit rate, and that seemed to resolve the issue.

@l'L'l This doesn't seem to be making any difference.

@JakubKotrs I tried your suggestion, but the outcome continued to be the same. I piped the stream and also wrapped the child process in a transform stream.

Maybe ，you can try as
  const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-maxrate', '3000k',
    '-bufsize', '6000k',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-g', '50',
    '-f', 'flv',
    'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MY_KEY'
  ]);

remove the first '-f flv'

Ah, thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve it. Extra -f switch would just replace the first one with the same value "flv". Removed it, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Try to send audio stream with video, even dummy. Some streaming services like youtube, etc, may require audio stream with video. Something like that:
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-f', 'lavfi',
    '-i', 'anullsrc',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-maxrate', '3000k',
    '-bufsize', '6000k',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-g', '50',
    '-c:a', 'aac',
    '-f', 'flv',
    'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MY_KEY'
  ]);

